# LWJGL Text being transformed with the 3D scene

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, lwjgl

I am trying to make a game for a school project using LWJGL and have recently been having a problem with text. My problem is that whenever I try to draw text to the screen, it moves and gets transformed with the 3D scene as if it is a 3D object. I'm not sure if there is some clear method that I am supposed to be using to reset the shader being applied, but if there is that would be great. This is my first project with LWJGL, and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I have put some releveant methods and classes below, but the full source code is at https://github.com/SomeRandomPerson9/3DT

My render method:

```
public static void renderScene(){
    if(selectedScene.sceneType == SceneType.THREE_DIMENSIONAL) {

        for (RenderObject renderObject : selectedScene.getObjects()) {

            for(Mesh meshyThing : renderObject.getMeshs().values()){        
                selectedScene.getRegShader().bind();
                selectedScene.getRegShader().updateUniforms(renderObject.getTransform().getTransformation(), renderObject.getTransform().getProjectedTransformation(new Matrix4f().initTranslation(renderObject.getLocation().GetX(), renderObject.getLocation().GetY(), renderObject.getLocation().GetZ())), renderObject.getMaterial(meshyThing.getRequiredMtl()));
                meshyThing.draw();
            }
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadMatrix(selectedScene.getOrthographicProjectionMatrix());
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        for(GenericObject genericObject : selectedScene.getOverlayObjects()){
            if(genericObject instanceof TextObject){
                TextObject textObj = (TextObject)genericObject;
                try {
                    glPushMatrix();
                    glLoadIdentity();
                    //glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
                    ProgramRefrence.fonts.arialFont.drawString(10, 10, "EulerCamera: [x=" + ProgramRefrence.formatters.hundredths.format(selectedScene.getCamera().getPos().GetX()) +
                            ",y=" + ProgramRefrence.formatters.hundredths.format(selectedScene.getCamera().getPos().GetY()) + ",z=" + ProgramRefrence.formatters.hundredths.format(selectedScene.getCamera().getPos().GetZ()) + "]");
                    //glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
                    glPopMatrix();
                }catch(NullPointerException e){

                }
            }                
        }

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadMatrix(selectedScene.getPerspectiveProjectionMatrix());
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    }
    else if(selectedScene.sceneType == SceneType.TWO_DIMENSIONAL){
        if(selectedScene instanceof Scene2DVideo){

            ((Scene2DVideo) selectedScene).render();
        }
    }
}
```

Where getPerspectiveProjectionMatrix() and getOrthographicProjectionMatrix() are defined.

```
public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    this.camera = camera;
    this.getCamera().applyPerspectiveMatrix();
    GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, perspectiveProjectionMatrix);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);
    GL11.glGetFloat(GL11.GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, orthographicProjectionMatrix);
    GL11.glLoadMatrix(perspectiveProjectionMatrix);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);

}
```

What getRegShader() returns:

```
package com.harry9137.api.render.shaders;

import com.harry9137.api.render.Material;
import com.harry9137.api.util.ResourceLoader;
import com.harry9137.api.render.math.Matrix4f;
import com.harry9137.api.render.math.Vector3f;
import com.harry9137.api.render.lighting.BaseLight;
import com.harry9137.api.render.lighting.DirectionalLight;
import com.harry9137.api.util.RenderUtil;

import org.newdawn.slick.Color;

import java.awt.*;

public class PhongShader extends Shader {
    private static final PhongShader instance = new PhongShader();

public static PhongShader getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private static Vector3f ambientLight = new Vector3f(0.1f,0.1f,0.1f);
private static DirectionalLight directionalLight = new DirectionalLight(new BaseLight(new Vector3f(1,1,1), 0f), new Vector3f(0,0,0));

private PhongShader() {
    super();

    addVertexShader(ResourceLoader.loadShader("phongVertex.vs"));
    addFragmentShader(ResourceLoader.loadShader("phongFragment.fs"));
    compileShader();

    addUniform("transform");
    addUniform("baseColor");
    addUniform("ambientLight");

    addUniform("directionalLight.base.color");
    addUniform("directionalLight.base.intensity");
    addUniform("directionalLight.direction");
}

public static DirectionalLight getDirectionalLight() {
    return directionalLight;
}

public static void setDirectionalLight(DirectionalLight directionalLight) {
    PhongShader.directionalLight = directionalLight;
}

public void updateUniforms(Matrix4f worldMatrix, Matrix4f projectedMatrix, Material material) {
    setUniform("transform", projectedMatrix.mul(worldMatrix));
    if(material != null && material.getColor() != null) {
        setUniform("baseColor", material.getColor());
    }
    else{
        setUniform("baseColor", new Vector3f(255,255,255));
        //Color.white.bind();
    }

    if (material != null && material.getTexture() != null) {
        material.getTexture().bind();
    }
    else
        RenderUtil.unbindTextures();

    setUniform("ambientLight", ambientLight);

    setUniform("directionalLight", directionalLight);
}

public static Vector3f getAmbientLight() {
    return ambientLight;
}

public static void setAmbientLight(Vector3f ambientLight) {
    PhongShader.ambientLight = ambientLight;
}
public void setUniform(String uniformName, BaseLight baseLight){
    setUniform(uniformName + ".color", baseLight.getColor());
    setUniformf(uniformName + ".intensity", baseLight.getIntensity());
}
public void setUniform(String uniformName, DirectionalLight directionalLight)
{
    setUniform(uniformName + ".base", directionalLight.getBase());
    setUniform(uniformName + ".direction", directionalLight.getDirection());
}
}
```

Comment: you want to draw a 2d overlay over the scene and put your text there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. How would you do that differently than its already being done?